# concurrent I/O - buffers corruption, block device driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I developing block layered device driver. So, I intercept **WRITE** request and encrypt data, and decrypt data in the `end_bio()` routine (during processing and **READ** request).
So all works fine in single stream. But I getting buffers content corruption if have tried to performs I/O from two and more processes simultaneously. I have not any local storage for buffers.

**Do I'm need to count a BIO merging in my driver?**

**Is the Linux I/O subsystem have some requirements related to the a number of concurrent I/O request?**

**Is there some tips and tricks related stack using or compilation?**

This is under kernel 4.15.

At the time I use next constriction to run over disk sectors:

```
    /*
     * A portion of the bio_copy_data() ...
     */
    for (vcnt = 0, src_iter = src->bi_iter; ; vcnt++)
        {
        if ( !src_iter.bi_size)
            {
            if ( !(src = src->bi_next) )
                break;

            src_iter = src->bi_iter;
            }

        src_bv = bio_iter_iovec(src, src_iter);

        src_p = bv_page = kmap_atomic(src_bv.bv_page);
        src_p += src_bv.bv_offset;

        nlbn    = src_bv.bv_len512;
        for ( ; nlbn--; lbn++ , src_p += 512 )
                {
                {
                /* Simulate a processing of data in the I/O buffer */
               char *srcp = src_p, *dstp = src_p;
               int  count = DUDRV$K_SECTORSZ;

               while ( count--)
                {
                *(dstp++) = ~ (*(srcp++));
                }

                }
                }
        kunmap_atomic(bv_page);
        **bio_advance_iter**(src, &src_iter, src_bv.bv_len);
        }
```

Is this correct ? Or I'm need to use something like **bio_for_each_segment(bvl, bio, iter) **   ?

Comment: Did the answer below helped you somehow? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, no. I'll post an answer just later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The root of the problem is a "feature" of the Block I/O methods. In particularly (see description at Linex site [reference](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/biovecs.txt) )*

** Biovecs **can be shared between multiple bios** - a bvec iter can represent an
   arbitrary range of an existing biovec, both starting and ending midway
   through biovecs. This is what enables efficient splitting of arbitrary
   bios. Note that this means we *only* use bi_size to determine when we've
   reached the end of a bio, not bi_vcnt - and the bio_iovec() macro takes
   bi_size into account when constructing biovecs.*

*So, in my case this is a cause of the buffer with disk sector overrun.*

*The trick is set **REQ_NOMERGE_FLAGS** in the **.bi_opf** before sending BIO to backed device driver.*

*The second reason is the non-actual **.bi_iter** is returned by backed device driver. So, we need to save it (before submiting BIO request to backend)  and restore it in the our "**bio_endio()**" routine.*

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the use of [vmap](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-vmap.html) with global synchronization, instead?

The use of kmap_atomic has some restrictions:

> Since the mapping is restricted to the CPU that issued it, it
>   performs well, but the issuing task is therefore required to stay on that
>   CPU until it has finished, lest some other task displace its mappings.
>
> kmap_atomic() may also be used by interrupt contexts, since it is does not
>   sleep and the caller may not sleep until after kunmap_atomic() is called.

Reference: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/highmem.txt

Comment: Thanks for attempt, @Fabio! I have found a root of the problem see my answer below.