# bio_endio - how to get disk sectors content

Tags: linux-device-driver

*At the time I have tried to use construction like:*

```
__my_bio_endio (struct bio *iob)
{
struct bvec_iter src_iter;
struct bio_vec src_bv;
sector_t sector = iob->bi_iter.bi_sector;
unsigned int len, segno = 0;
```

...

```
    $TRACE("%s %s BIO=%p (op=%#x), sector=%lu, .bi_vcnt=%u, .bi_status=%d",
           pref ? pref : "",
           bio_data_dir(iob) == WRITE ? "WRITE" : "READ", iob,
           bio_op(iob),
           sector, iob->bi_vcnt, iob->bi_status);


    bio_for_each_segment (src_bv, iob, src_iter)
        {
        $TRACE("%s bvec[segno=%3.3u]: page/len/offset : %p/%u/%u",
               pref ? pref : "",
               segno, src_bv.bv_page, src_bv.bv_len, src_bv.bv_offset);

        len = src_bv.bv_len;
        sector += len >> SECTOR_SHIFT;
        segno++;
        }
```

...
    }

*READ Request args:*

```
READ (op=0x0) BIO=000000004debb98a, .bi_sector=2048, .bi_vcnt=1
```

*It's only what I see in the:*

```
READ BIO=000000004debb98a (op=0x0), sector=2056, .bi_vcnt=1, .bi_status=0
```

*It expects that in the loop I'll see (and modify if need)  disk sectors has been read from disk volume - but nothing.*

***So, can someone help me to understand how to access disk buffers content with example ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It need to save .bi_iter field before submiting BIO request to backend device driver, and restore it in the __my_bio_endio () routine.
 So more details of processing concurrent BIO is described in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52005791/concurrent-i-o-buffers-corruption-block-device-driver)